# How to evaluate community detection without ground truth

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, modularity

I have performed community detection on a graph and would like to evaluate how good my algorithm was in multiple ways.

Right now I have the start graph, and lists of nodes representing extracted communities. I have no ground truth pertaining to what these communities actually are.

I know modularity is one good metric for assessing my algorithm. I was wondering if there are any others (bonus if know off hand where code for these methods exists)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modularity indeed is a widely used measure and has a lot of different extensions regarding how you define your graph and communities; for example whether your graph is directed or undirected, and whether your communities are distinct or overlapping. Also there are some modularity metrics regarding fuzzy memberships.

But modularity compares the clustering to an otherwise randomly generate graph. There is some debate in general about how good of a measure modularity is.(refer to Fortunato 2010).

I think one model free evidence for the goodness of the communities is the a similar argument but from the density point of view. One major argument about the existence of communities is the fact that within clusters are denser than across cluster connections. So, in other words you can look into the density of the link within a community and compare to the link from a community to outside. If you call the density at the network level to be at d, and within a specific cluster at d_in, and across the cluster and the outside world d_out, then you should have:

```
d_in > d > d_out
```

.